# React native autocomplete input list could not display while button exist after the component

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I am new in react native i might be missing some easy tricks. I have a autocomplete input. When i write some text, List items are staying below the button. I have to update my css codes but when i try change all of item but could not be success. How can i update css fields for this problem.

```
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

          <Item rounded style={{margin: 10}}>
          <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={styles.container}
          inputContainerStyle={{borderWidth: 0}}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={this.state.places}
          defaultValue={this.state.placeQuery}
          onChangeText={text => this.findPlace(text)}
          placeholder="Arazi Lokasyonu"
          placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressFn(item.name, item.lat, item.lon)}>
                  <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                      <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                      {item.name !== item.address && '\n' + item.address}
                  </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}/>
          </Item>
          <Button block
            style={{margin: 10}}
            onPress={() => this.addLand(this.state.landName)}>
            <Text>Ekle</Text>
          </Button>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 25,
    },
    autocompleteContainer: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        height:50,
        borderRadius: 30,
        flex: 1,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 1,
    },
    itemText: {
        fontSize: 25,
        margin: 2,
    },
});
```

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue. I guess it has to do with the fact that react native automatically gives elements that come after another a higher zIndex. But I do not yet have found a working workaround myself.